# Missing Push Notification Entitlement Troubles in Ionic App using OneSignal

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, onesignal

i'm using the OneSignal API for Push Notifications in an Cordova App. My android is receiving notifications, but the iPhone isn't and i'm receiving this e-mail:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "----". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to
>   correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app includes an API for
>   Apple's Push Notification service, but the aps-environment entitlement
>   is missing from the app's signature. To resolve this, make sure your
>   App ID is enabled for push notification in the Provisioning Portal.
>   Then, sign your app with a distribution provisioning profile that
>   includes the aps-environment entitlement. This will create the correct
>   signature, and you can resubmit your app. See "Provisioning and
>   Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for
>   more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification
>   service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future
>   submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework,
>   you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the
>   API.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

My App ID is enabled for push notifications and i really don't understand why it isn't working.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable "Push Notifications" in your project settings. Check attached the screenshot.

[image]